# JADE ACLMessage InReplyTo and ReplyWith

Tags: java, agents-jade

I am trying to create a JADE message with

```
                ACLMessage reqMsg = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
```

Basically, there are fields in this message that I can populate as I see in the API by using some setters. However, I dont understand the ***setInReplyTo*** and ***setReplyWith*** methods since I couldnt find enough explanation. What exactly I can use these fields/methods for ?

Comment: I looked through one of the projects I did in college, but I could not find anything that might help you. However, as the API docs for ACLMessage suggest, the methods set the `in-reply-to` and `reply-with` slots of the message. To see what exactly they do, you can follow the official [FIPA spec](http://www.fipa.org/specs/fipa00061/SC00061G.pdf). Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks it describes on the page 5. reply-with:Introduces an expression that will be used by the responding agent to identify this message. The reply-with parameter is designed to be used to follow a conversation thread in a situation where multiple 
206  dialogues occur simultaneously. For example, if agent i sends to agent j a message which contains "reply-with <expr>" Agent j will respond with a message containing "in-reply-to <expr>"

Comment: @AndreiSuceava you can post these if you want as an answer so I can accept your answer in the "formal" way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods set the `in-reply-to` and `reply-with` message fields. The [FIPA Specification](http://www.fipa.org/specs/fipa00061/SC00061G.pdf) describes these fields (as well as all the other ones) in detail.